# Discord Bot, make it do something without an event

Tags: python, bots, discord, tornado

Hi im trying to send commands to a discord throug a webinterface but without any of the @bot.event definitions.
Only problem is I don't get a referenced ctx object that I can use to find what channel the bot is in etc.

Is there any way to make this work without the bot events? I've looked at few other codes but nothing comes close to what i'm trying to achieve.

I created a work around by getting the Guild_ID as a global from the on_ready event. But can seem to find the ctx for the bot. Any ideas or references to other work is very welcome so I can continue this project :)

bot.py:

```
import discord
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import sys
import asyncio
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import os
import socket


if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


soundFolderLocation = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\\sounds\\"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
GUILD_ID = '' 
BOT_TOKEN = ''

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')
    #channel = list(bot.get_all_channels())
    #length = len(channel)
    #for i in range(length):
        #print(channel[i].name + ' id:' + str(channel[i].id))
    print('logged in')
    print('bot name : '+str(bot.user.name))
    print('bot ID : '+str(bot.user.id))
    print('discord version : '+str(discord.__version__))
    print('GuildID : '+str(bot.guilds[0]))

    GUILD_ID = bot.guilds[0]


class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    # you can pass whatever you want
    def initialize(self, bot, db):
        self.bot = bot

    async def prepare(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

class SoundboardHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def tornado_sounds(self):
        serverFolder = soundFolderLocation + "\\"
        soundList = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(serverFolder):
            for filename in files:
                sound = filename.replace(".mp3", "")
                soundList.append(sound)
        soundsofawsome = soundList
        return soundsofawsome

    def get(self):
        items = self.tornado_sounds()
        self.render("bot_template.html", title="Thanos", items=items)

class tornado_playsound(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
            global GUILD_ID
            global bot
            serverFolder = soundFolderLocation + "\\"
            voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=GUILD_ID)
            for member in bot.get_all_members():
             if 'Thanos' in str(member):
              user = member
            print("Member has been found:" +str(member))
  #### everything stops working here!!              
  channel = member.voice.channel
            playthissound = serverFolder + str(self.request.body) + ".mp3"
            if voice and voice.is_connected():
              if ctx.message.author.voice.channel != voice.channel:
                await voice.move_to(channel)
              else:
                voice = await channel.connect()
            voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
            voice.source.volume = 0.5
            voice.play(
              discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(playthissound),
              after=lambda e: print(
              f"[SOUND] [{ctx.guild.id}] [{ctx.guild}] [{ctx.author.name}] [STOP] {self.request.body}.mp3"
                ),
              )



# what is passed to inilialize
extra = {
    "my_bot_instance": bot,
    "my_database": "I'm a database",
}


routes = [
    (r"/", SoundboardHandler),
    (r"/playsound", tornado_playsound),
]


settings = {
    "cookie_secret": "1234",
}
app = tornado.web.Application(routes, settings)
app.listen(4242)
myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print('*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(bot.start(BOT_TOKEN), loop=loop)
loop.run_forever()
```

template:

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).off('click').on('click', 'body', function(event){
      if ( $( event.target ).is( ":button" ) ) {
        respons = event.target.id
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/playsound",
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            data: respons,
            success: function (data) {
                                     $("#debugfield").text("clicked something and it worked" + respons);
                                     },
            error: function (error) {
                                    $("#debugfield").text("Error to load API");
                                    }
        });
      }
    });
</script>
     <ul id="soundbuttons">
       {% for item in items %}
         <li>
          <button class="button" id="{{escape(item)}}" type="button">{{escape(item)}}</button>
          <br/>
         </li>
       {% end %}
     </ul>
   <span id="responsefield"></span>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The bot isn't "in" a channel the same way a human using discord is.  It can send and receive messages from all of the channels it can see simultaneously.  The discord.py  is an event-driven framework, it's really not designed to be used in an imperative programming way.  You might look into discord webhooks instead.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you just gave me the push in the right direction, Ill make the bot listen for messages in a separate hidden channel, and send messages through webhooks there. Feel like a redundant path since the code I want to execute is right next to it in the same python script. But since the python framework is based on messages that come back, and extrapolate the guild and users from those messages it makes sense.